# mongodb query map by key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following structure in mongodb:

```
person:
   {
     "1" [personId] : ["some_text", "some_text"],
     "2" [personId] : ["some_text", "some_text"],
     "3" [personId] : ["some_text", "some_text"]
   }
```

I would like to query a person map structure and get only values when `personid` (key) is between 1 to 2

I try to use `$elemMatch` but its not a good idea because I would like query by a dynamic range.

I use map strucute becuase I have another process that insert person data dynamically by person id.

Is there any way to filter map structure data by key?

Thanks

Comment: is `person` a field in a collection or the collection name itself?

Comment: @chridam person is a field in the collection

Answer (score 0):

The code is not actually tested. But this might work:

```js
const searchParams = [
    { $elemMatch: { fieldA: "val1", fieldB: "val2" } },
    { $elemMatch: { fieldC: "val3", fieldD: "val4" } },
]

const results = await yourDB.find({
    person: {
        $in: searchParam
    }
})
```

The elements of `searchParams` can be dynamically generated based on your need.

```
searchParams.psuh({ $elemMatch: { fieldX: "val_x", fieldZ: "val_z })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an to run an aggregate operation where you can convert the hash map into an array of key value documents, filter the array based on the above condition and convert the filtered array back to the hash map.

Take for instance the following operation, it uses the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) pipeline step to do the above operations with the aid of the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operators:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields':  {
        'person': {
            '$arrayToObject': { 
                '$filter': {
                    'input': { '$objectToArray': '$person' },
                    'cond': { 
                        '$in': ['$$this.k', ['1', '2']]    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```